# PySpark UDF to test conversion from String to Int

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

I want to apply a udf function which return original value only if it can be converted to int. Til now I tried 2 functions :

```
def nb_int(s):
    try:
        val=int(s)
        return s
    except:
        return "ERROR"

def nb_digit(s):
    if (s.isdigit() == True):
        return s
    else:
        return "ERROR"
nb_udf = F.udf(nb_digit, StringType())
df_corrected=df.withColumn("IntValue",nb_udf("nb_value"))
```

I applied this function on "nb_value". But it's not working :

```
df_corrected.filter(df_corrected["IntValue"] == "ERROR").select("nb_value").dropDuplicates(subset=["nb_value"]).collect()
```

Results of the last line should only give me values which are not convertible, but I still have 1, 2, 4, etc ...

```
[Row(nb_value=u'MS'),
 Row(nb_value=u'286'),
 Row(nb_value=u'TB'),
 Row(nb_value=u'GF'),
 Row(nb_value=u'287'),
 Row(nb_value=u'MU'),
 Row(nb_value=u'170'),
 Row(nb_value=u'A9'),
 Row(nb_value=u'288'),
 Row(nb_value=u'171'),
 Row(nb_value=u'333'),....
```

Any help to fix it is welcome ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both your UDFs work for me. You'd better use the second one, because raising exceptions can slow spark down. The `== True` is redundant in `nb_digit`, but apart from that it's fine:

First let's create the example dataframe:

```py
df = hc.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['MS'],['286'],['TB'],['GF'],['287'],['MU'],['170'],['A9'],['288'],['171'],['333']]), ["nb_value"])
```

Using any of your UDFs:

```py
df_corrected = df.withColumn("IntValue", nb_udf("nb_value"))
df_corrected.filter(df_corrected["IntValue"] == "ERROR").select("nb_value").dropDuplicates(subset=["nb_value"]).collect()

[Row(nb_value=u'MS'),
 Row(nb_value=u'TB'),
 Row(nb_value=u'GF'),
 Row(nb_value=u'A9'),
 Row(nb_value=u'MU')]
```